# Get the sum of values per date while obtaining recent value per date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a table, movements, that shows the user's use of their card.
It's something like this:

| movementdate | expense | deposit | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-09 19:23:49 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-07-09 20:40:13 | 0 | 6 | 8 |
| 2021-07-09 13:50:01 | 0 | 2 | 10 |
| 2021-07-10 11:50:31 | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| 2021-07-10 12:59:15 | 0 | 5 | 10 |
| 2021-07-10 18:01:39 | 10 | 0 | 0 |

It shows their deposits and expenses, and also shows their final balance.
I have this query that gets the total of deposits and expenses per day;

```
select EXTRACT(day FROM m.movementdate) as d, EXTRACT(month FROM m.movementdate) as m, 
       EXTRACT(year FROM m.movementdate) as y, sum(m.expense) as TotalExpense, 
       sum (m.deposit) as TotalDeposit
from movements m 
group by 3,2,1
```

But I want to get also the last record of their balance per day.

something like this:

| Date | TotalExpense | TotalDeposit | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-09 | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-07-10 | 15 | 5 | 0 |

How could I get this last part? I have found some ways to get the last balance of the day, but I can't figure out how to include it in the same query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another method to desired achieve the result is using window function `row_number()`

Here is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0be2d5c14d6fa4c91566584c6e867583)

```
with cte as
(
  select 
    movementdate::date as dt,
    EXTRACT(day FROM movementdate) as d,
    EXTRACT(month FROM movementdate) as m, 
    EXTRACT(year FROM movementdate) as y,
    sum(expense) over (partition by movementdate::date) as expense,
    sum(deposit) over (partition by movementdate::date) as deposit,
    balance,
    row_number() over (partition by movementdate::date order by movementdate desc) as rn
  from movements
)

select 
  dt,
  d, 
  m, 
  y, 
  expense, 
  deposit, 
  balance
from cte
where rn = 1
order by
  1, 2, 3
```

output:

```
*-------------------------------------------------------*
|  dt          d    m   y     expense   deposit  balance|
*-------------------------------------------------------*
| 2021-07-09    9   7   2021    0         10       8    |
| 2021-07-10    10  7   2021    15         5       0    |
*-------------------------------------------------------*
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One method uses arrays:

```
select EXTRACT(day FROM m.movementdate) as d,
       EXTRACT(month FROM m.movementdate) as m, 
       EXTRACT(year FROM m.movementdate) as y,
       sum(m.expense) as TotalExpense, 
       sum (m.deposit) as TotalDeposit,
       (array_agg(m.balance order by m.movementdate desc))[1] as balance
from movements m 
group by 3,2,1;
```

I would also suggest that you use `m.movementdate::date` instead of defining the first three columns.

Answer (score 1):

###### Another option is to use [PostgreSQL `LATERAL Subquery`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html)

Something like:

```sql
WITH movements_per_day AS (
  select m.movementdate::date AS dt
     , EXTRACT(day FROM m.movementdate) as d
     , EXTRACT(month FROM m.movementdate) as m
     , EXTRACT(year FROM m.movementdate) as y
     , sum(m.expense) as TotalExpense
     , sum (m.deposit) as TotalDeposit
  from movements m
  group by 1,2,3,4
)
SELECT movements_per_day.*, last_movement.balance
  FROM movements_per_day
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT movements.balance
    FROM movements
    WHERE movements.movement_date::date = movements_per_day.dt
    ORDER BY movements.movementdate DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS last_movement
```

As the other answers suggest, it's a bit simpler to use the `m.movementdate::date` instead of the first three columns.